# Remote shutdown with a shutdown reason code

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I'd like to power off a remote machine by Stop-Computer command in PowerShell. Is there any way to send a shutdown reason code (like `Hardware: Maintenance (Planned)`) as if choosing during local shutdown?

Comment: Not with Stop-Computer, but you can still call shutdown.exe and use the switches for reason code.

Comment: Could you post your comment as an answer?